# Adding sticker on top of bbox frame

Tags: asymptote

I'm using following asymptote code.

```
size(6cm,4cm,false);
import graph;

real f(real x) {return sqrt(x);}
real xmin=0, xmax=50, xStep = 5, xstep = 0;
real ymin=0, ymax=7, yStep = 1, ystep = 0;

draw(graph(f,xmin,xmax,n=200),1bp+blue);

xlimits(xmin,xmax,crop=true); 
ylimits(ymin,ymax,crop=true); 

xaxis(BottomTop,nullpen,Ticks("%",extend=true,Step=xStep,step=xstep,pTick=mediumgrey,ptick=lightgrey));
yaxis(LeftRight,nullpen,Ticks("%",extend=true,Step=yStep,step=ystep,pTick=mediumgrey,ptick=lightgrey));

ticks Tx = Ticks(Label(fontsize(5pt)),Step=xStep,step=xstep,pTick=black,ptick=black,NoZero,Size=2,size=1);
xaxis(Tx,Arrow(size=3),above=true);

ticks Ty = Ticks(shift(0,1)*Label(fontsize(5pt)),Step=yStep,step=ystep,pTick=black,ptick=black,NoZero,Size=2,size=1);
yaxis(Ty,Arrow(size=3),above=true);

shipout(bbox(xmargin=1mm,red+1bp));
```

[image: graph]

I need to had something (a small sticker with number inside) on top of the upper left corner of the picture. I tested several ways without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.  I modified your code to add a boxed label after the bounding box is drawn but before shipout.

I located the box and label by trial and error.  For example, I don't know why the "ySticker" variable must be so large.

```
size(6cm,4cm,false);
import graph;

real f(real x) {return sqrt(x);}
real xmin=0, xmax=50, xStep = 5, xstep = 0;
real ymin=0, ymax=7, yStep = 1, ystep = 0;

draw(graph(f,xmin,xmax,n=200),1bp+blue);

xlimits(xmin,xmax,crop=true); 
ylimits(ymin,ymax,crop=true); 

xaxis(BottomTop,nullpen,Ticks("%",extend=true,Step=xStep,step=xstep,pTick=mediumgrey,ptick=lightgrey));
yaxis(LeftRight,nullpen,Ticks("%",extend=true,Step=yStep,step=ystep,pTick=mediumgrey,ptick=lightgrey));

ticks Tx = Ticks(Label(fontsize(5pt)),Step=xStep,step=xstep,pTick=black,ptick=black,NoZero,Size=2,size=1);
xaxis(Tx,Arrow(size=3),above=true);

ticks Ty = Ticks(shift(0,1)*Label(fontsize(5pt)),Step=yStep,step=ystep,pTick=black,ptick=black,NoZero,Size=2,size=1);
yaxis(Ty,Arrow(size=3),above=true);

frame f = bbox(xmargin=1mm,red+1bp,Draw);

real xSticker = 0.0;
real ySticker = 110.0;
filldraw(f, shift(xSticker,ySticker)*scale(15.0,8.0)*shift(-0.5,-0.5)*unitsquare, white, black);
label(f, scale(0.5)*"test", (xSticker,ySticker));

shipout(f);
```

[image]

Comment: Thx. But I was trying to put the label outside the red rectangle ?

Comment: @MB4E:  See my edited answer above.

Comment: Why `ySticker` variable must be so large: its units are points. The `size` function (and similar functions like `unitsize`) apply to `picture` objects. But `f` is a `frame` -- which is what you get when you resolve all the distances into points (postscript points, I think). Any time you manipulate frames, everything is measured in points. Note that without resolving distances into points, you cannot compute a bounding box that includes text.

Answer (score 2):

I propose here two solutions without experimentation about the value of the position of the sticker.
The first solution consists in playing with frame. If `ff` is the frame containing the graph + bounding box, the function `max(ff)`, `min(ff)` allow to obtain the coordinate of the bounding box (recall, see the documentation, that frames are canvas for drawing in PostScript coordinates). So the coordinates of the point where adding the sticker are well known, and it is sufficient to add 5bp in x and y coordinates. It avoids one to find a proper value of `ySticker` and it is the opportunity to play with `align`. Please find the code

```
  size(6cm,4cm,false);
  import graph;

  real f(real x) {return sqrt(x);}
  real xmin=0, xmax=50, xStep = 5, xstep = 0;
  real ymin=0, ymax=7, yStep = 1, ystep = 0;

  draw(graph(f,xmin,xmax,n=200),1bp+blue);

  xlimits(xmin,xmax,crop=true); 
  ylimits(ymin,ymax,crop=true); 

  xaxis(BottomTop,nullpen,Ticks("%",extend=true,Step=xStep,step=xstep,pTick=mediumgrey,ptick=lightgrey));
  yaxis(LeftRight,nullpen,Ticks("%",extend=true,Step=yStep,step=ystep,pTick=mediumgrey,ptick=lightgrey));

  ticks Tx = Ticks(Label(fontsize(5pt)),Step=xStep,step=xstep,pTick=black,ptick=black,NoZero,Size=2,size=1);
  xaxis(0,50,Tx,Arrow(size=3),above=true);

  ticks Ty = Ticks(shift(0,1)*Label(fontsize(5pt)),Step=yStep,step=ystep,pTick=black,ptick=black,NoZero,Size=2,size=1);
  yaxis(0,7,Ty,Arrow(size=3),above=true);


  frame ff = bbox(xmargin=1mm,red+1bp,Draw);

  frame sticker;
  (box(sticker,scale(.5)*"test test test"));


  frame fin;
  add(fin,ff);
  pair sposm =min(ff);
  pair sposM= max(ff);
  add(ff,shift((min(ff).x+5bp,max(ff).y+5bp))*(align(sticker,Align)));
  add(ff,shift(sposM.x,sposM.y)*(align(sticker,(-Align.x,Align.y))));
  shipout(ff);
```

and the result
[image]

The second solution is to create a picture `pic1` containing the graph and the bounding box which gives a frame `ff`. Then a (current) picture is created, adding first `ff`. To add the label to the right place, I use the `truepoint` function which allows one to place a point on the boundary of a picture. It is a specific function since a picture is a high level structure, the size constraints are performed at the end, the boundary can vary from line to line. I added two different `align` tests. Please find the code

```
  picture pic1;
  size(pic1,6cm,4cm,false);
  import graph;

  real f(real x) {return sqrt(x);}
  real xmin=0, xmax=50, xStep = 5, xstep = 0;
  real ymin=0, ymax=7, yStep = 1, ystep = 0;

  draw(pic1,graph(f,xmin,xmax,n=200),1bp+blue);

  xlimits(pic1,xmin,xmax,crop=true); 
  ylimits(pic1,ymin,ymax,crop=true); 

  xaxis(pic1,BottomTop,nullpen,Ticks("%",extend=true,Step=xStep,step=xstep,pTick=mediumgrey,ptick=lightgrey));
  yaxis(pic1,LeftRight,nullpen,Ticks("%",extend=true,Step=yStep,step=ystep,pTick=mediumgrey,ptick=lightgrey));

  ticks Tx = Ticks(Label(fontsize(5pt)),Step=xStep,step=xstep,pTick=black,ptick=black,NoZero,Size=2,size=1);
  xaxis(pic1,0,50,Tx,Arrow(size=3),above=true);

  ticks Ty = Ticks(shift(0,1)*Label(fontsize(5pt)),Step=yStep,step=ystep,pTick=black,ptick=black,NoZero,Size=2,size=1);
  yaxis(pic1,0,7,Ty,Arrow(size=3),above=true);


  frame ff = bbox(pic1,xmargin=1mm,red+1bp,Draw);

  add(ff);
  frame sticker;
  (box(sticker,scale(.5)*"test test test"));
  add(align(sticker,N+E),truepoint(W+N));
  add(align(sticker,-Align),truepoint(S+E));
  dot(truepoint(W));
  dot(truepoint(E));
  dot(truepoint(S));
```

and the picture
[image]